# OpenCV kmean: how to choose decent values for COUNT and EPS?

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to use the kmean function in OpenCV to pre-classify 36000 sample images into 100+ classes (to reduce my work to prepare train data for supervised learning). In this function there are two parameters which I do not really understand: **cv::TermCriteria::EPS** and  **cv::TermCriteria::COUNT**.

```
cv::kmeans(dataset.t(), K, kmean_labels, cv::TermCriteria( cv::TermCriteria::EPS + cv::TermCriteria::COUNT, 10, 1.0),
            3, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, kmean_centers);
```

In OpenCV documents, it explains that:
**cv::TermCriteria::EPS**: the desired accuracy or change in parameters at which the iterative algorithm stops.

**cv::TermCriteria::COUNT**: the maximum number of iterations or elements to compute.

The explanation above is not quite clear for me. Can anyone help to explain more and show how to find good values for COUNT and EPS?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no magical numbers that will fit all applications (otherwise they wouldn't be parameters).

Kmeans is an iterative algorithm, which will move towards an optimum and each iteration should get better, but you need to tell your algorithm when to stop.

Using **cv::TermCriteria::COUNT**, you tell the algorithm: you can perform `x` iterations, then stop. But this doesn't guarantee you any precision.

Using **cv::TermCriteria::EPS**, you tell the algorithm to continue its iterations, untill the difference between two successive iterations becomes *sufficiently* small. The parameter `EPS` tell the algorithm how small this difference should become. This depends of course on the dataset that you are feeding to the algorithm. Suppose you multiply all your data points by 10; then EPS should vary accordingly (quadratically I suppose, but not sure about that).

When you use **both** both parameters; you tell the algorithm to stop when one of both conditions is fullfilled; for example: stop iterating when the difference between two successive runs is smaller than 0.1, **OR** when you have done 10 iterations.

**in conclusion**: only analysis of your datasets, and trial and error can give you *decent* values...

Comment: thank you very much, your answer helps me to understand more :D